# How do I make the woocommerce message disappear after 5 seconds?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For default, the woocommerce message will appear if the user click "the update cart button" or "add to cart button." How do I disappear the woocommerce message after 5 seconds if the user update the cart ( click the update cart button) ? So I want to message appear but also disappear after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.woocommerce-message').fadeOut('fast');
}, 5000); // <-- time in mseconds
```

Comment: where do i add this? which file?

Comment: in your header.php before </head> tag if you don't understand then wait I will update my answer

Comment: Can I put this inside my main.js file?

Comment: Appreciated. can you help me with this question? can't find any solution. Can you reply here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829637/is-there-a-way-display-the-product-price-in-woocommerce-thankyou-page

Comment: Why do I have clear my browser cache , so it will the message will disappear ? Everytime I test or comment out the js code, I have to clear my browser. and if I put the js code again, i have clear again. why? is there a reason? is there a way not the cleat the browser cache , everytime i make a change.

Comment: Also there is a glitch when the "message" appear and disappear. I think because its adding the message and removing the message??
I want it like this. If the message appear or disappear, it won't move. 
 http://alittlemorelikethis.com/collections/play/products/little-bugs-kids-tee